# Installing Linux ( Mint ) from one partition with Win 7 to an empty partition

Tags: linux, installation, linux-mint

I have no USB or DVD with me i do have Linux MINT ISO Image is there a way to install it on my second partition without burning the image to a CD/DVD/USB ?

Answer (score 1):

You will need a tool to achieve that:
- qemu or Virtualbok for running the installation from your image
Both are open source, you just need an internet connection.
Maybe Virtualbox is more convenient for you.

you just create a virtual machine with the linux-mint image as boot cd and you will have to add your empty partition to the virtual machine.
Provide some RAM (512 MB [or more]) and start your machine. 
Don't add an network card because if you have installed it on the empty partition you will reboot and start from there with your real NIC and that could cause some irritation which would need some manual configuration
After you started the Virtual machine you should be able to install Linux Mint on the virtual Disk (=empty partition) After half an hour (depends on your hardware) the installation is finished and suggests to reboot (this would concern only the virtual machine) 
Don't boot the virtual machine again.

Now the Win7 bootloader must be modified and told to give the option to boot from the new partition. Alternatively you can use grub for windows.

Now you can tell Win7 to reboot.

At restart you should now be able to select the new partition and you will be led to linux grub:
now it is getting interestiing: will the right partition be found?

I haven't done this yet, but i think it can work!

Answer (score 0):

Mount the ISO with daemon tools and see if Mint gives you the option from the CD. If not then the answer is no.